# Any other SelectorProvider ( default EPollSelectorProvider) at CentOS?

Tags: java, linux, centos, nio

Does any one know  if there is any other `SelectorProvider` other than `EPollSelectorProvider` for CentOS?

Or can you please tell me how to find available `SelectorProvider` thus I can specific in the `-Djava.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider`, therefore my applications can select other Providers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectorProvider` is discovered by analysising the rt.jar. It's called `sun.nio.ch.PollSelectorProvider`, by remove the "E".
So the mode can be achieved by:

```
-Djava.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider=sun.nio.ch.PollSelectorProvider
```

Which is found by `unzip rt.jar` and `grep Selector` [screen-shot_rt_grep_selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHwtw.png)

[By_Strings_JVM_libs_Poll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWIen.png)

Also, which is confirmed by EPOLL for Java Designer Mikhail, thanks Mikhail!

Comment: The poll based SelectorProvider is legacy. JDK 8 was the last JDK release to include it.